# Any documentation about mail with attachments to Outlook iOS app

Tags: ios, email, outlook, deep-linking, email-attachments

I'm creating an iOS App that must populates email info (subject, title, body, to, cc..) before sending it with Outlook (it's in case Apple Mail app is not available, so it's not a solution). I tried many solutions :

1. `ms-outlook://compose?to=&cc=&subject=&body=` : Can't attach any file (not even a `&attachment=<base64>` or something)
2. `UIActivityViewController` and `UIActivityItemProvider` inheritance : the **BEST effort** I found so far, able to provide subject, body AND attachments. But sadly, I can't populate To and Cc field and it's not documented. Worst, behavior changes from Outlook version to another
3. Found `ms-outlook-accepts-attachments` but I can't found any documentation on how to use it and if it satisfies my need.

I don't use O365 in my case, it's targeting **Exchange** mail services as well. So **I can't use Outlook API**...

**How can I populate EVERY Field (subject, To, Cc, body AND attachment) in a mail to send it with Outlook iOS app ?** A MHT file ? Something ?

Thank you very much for any help or piece of information